# Multiple Tomcat instances different JVM arguments for each

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, arguments

So i have to run multiple Tomcat instances on the same OS and i want to pass the same JVM Argument with different values for each Tomcat Instance. All i could find is them setting via

`export CATALINA_OPTS = "${CATALINA_OPTS} -Dmyparam=value"`

in setenv.sh.

But from what i know, all tomcat instances are accessing that environment variable, so whenever setenv.sh is called by starting a tomcat instance, i would overwrite the param for all other tomcat instances? If it is that way, is there another way to pass JVM arguments on startup for tomcat?

Comment: you don't need additional setting , if you need same params for each instance

Comment: do remember to keep separate port for each server , HTTP port and HTTPs port and theri respective re-direct ports

Comment: @AshishShetkar same param, but different value. Would your comment still apply?

Comment: no that is not possible on one single OS , if your param name is same - then it will be overridden - what you are trying to achieve is possible with something like VMs or cloud

Comment: Change the line in the `setenv.sh` to `export CATALINA_OPTS = "${CATALINA_OPTS} ${MYPARAM}"`, then use separate shell scripts to start each Tomcat instance, and in each shell script do `export MYPARAM=-Dmyparam=value`. If you can run each Tomcat instance under a separate user, even better.